# SPOJ "Pesel" challemge

Tags: python, optimization, programming-challenge, python-2.x

Here is a solution to the [SPOJ's JPESEL problem](http://pl.spoj.com/problems/JPESEL/). Basically the problem was to calculate cross product of 2 vectors modulo 10. If there is a positive remainder, it's not a valid [PESEL number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PESEL); (return `D`) if the remainder equals `0`, it's a valid number (return `N`).

```
import re, sys
n = input()
t = [1,3,7,9,1,3,7,9,1,3,1]
while(n):
    p = map(int, re.findall('.',sys.stdin.readline()))
    # Another approach I've tried in orer to save some memory - didn't help:
    # print 'D' if  sum([int(p[0]) * 1,int(p[1]) * 3,int(p[2]) * 7,int(p[3]) * 9,int(p[4]) * 1,int(p[5]) * 3,int(p[6]) * 7,int(p[7]) * 9,int(p[8]) * 1,int(p[9]) * 3,int(p[10]) * 1]) % 10 == 0 else 'N'
    print 'D' if ( sum(p*q for p,q in zip(t,p)) % 10 ) == 0 else 'N'
    n-=1
```

The solution above got the following results at SPOJ:

Time: 0.03s
Memory: 4.1M

where the best solutions (submitted in Python 2.7) got:

Time: 0.01s
Memory: 3.7M

How can I optimize this code in terms of time and memory used?

Note that I'm using different function to read the input, as `sys.stdin.readline()` is the fastest one when reading strings and `input()` when reading integers.

Comment: Why do you need to read from STDIN? I guess it will be faster with a file.

Comment: You mean to read the whole input at once? I need STDIN because that's how the program sumbitted to SPOJ should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace `re` module with just a `sys.stdin.readline()` and replace `zip` interator with `map` and `mul` function from [operator](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/operator.html) module like this:

```
from sys import stdin
from operator import mul

readline = stdin.readline
n = int(readline())
t = [1,3,7,9,1,3,7,9,1,3,1]

while n:
    p = map(int, readline().rstrip())
    print 'D' if (sum(map(mul, t, p)) % 10) == 0 else 'N'
    n -= 1
```

### Update

It seems getting item from a small dictionary is faster than `int` so there is a version without `int`:

```
from sys import stdin

readline = stdin.readline
val = {"0": 0, "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4, "5": 5, "6": 6,
       "7": 7, "8": 8, "9": 9}
val3 = {"0": 0, "1": 3, "2": 6, "3": 9, "4": 12, "5": 15, "6": 18,
        "7": 21, "8": 24, "9": 27}
val7 = {"0": 0, "1": 7, "2": 14, "3": 21, "4": 28, "5": 35, "6": 42,
        "7": 49, "8": 56, "9": 63}
val9 = {"0": 0, "1": 9, "2": 18, "3": 27, "4": 36, "5": 45, "6": 54,
        "7": 63, "8": 72, "9": 81}

n = int(readline())
while n:
    # Expects only one NL character at the end of the line
    p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, _ = readline()
    print 'D' if ((val[p1] + val3[p2] + val7[p3] + val9[p4]
                   + val[p5] + val3[p6] + val7[p7] + val9[p8]
                   + val[p9] + val3[p10] + val[p11]) % 10 == 0) else 'N'
    n -= 1
```

Comment: Much better time: `0.02` (is it because of using `readline()` instead of `input()`?), slightly better memory: `4.0M`.

Comment: (after your update) It's still slower than the best implementations on SPOJ but I've learned a few things - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Likely what is taking up extra time is the line:

```
 p = map(int, re.findall('.',sys.stdin.readline()))
```

There are a few things here. Firstly, regular expressions are relatively expensive. Underneath, it likely needs to compile the regular expression (which in this case is very simple, but still). Further, you don't need regular expressions to do this in python. For example, assume the string was something like `'343898934'`. Then this is equivalent to:

```
p = [int(k) for k in '343898934']
```

The above will likely be slightly faster.

The second place here that could be optimized (memory wise) is that `map` in Python 2.x returns a list as opposed to a generator. So instead we could do:

```
p = (int(k) for k in sys.stdin.readline())
```

The fact that this also removes the `re` import may also impact timing and memory usage, depending on how they measure.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it should run faster after such changes but I've changed my solution exactly as you said and now it's actually slower: time: `0.11`, memory: `4.5M`.

Comment: Interesting. I can understand that it might be slower (perhaps the overhead of setting up a generator here is worse than simply creating a small list). Likewise the memory usage. Perhaps try using the list comprehension version?

Comment: After changing to list comprehension: time: `0.12` (longer), memory: `4.5M` (same as before). I'm wondering whether this can be related to SPOJ's timing system.

Comment: `map` can be faster here (you can test it with [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/timeit.html) module). I think you should try `readline = sys.stdin.readline` before the loop and then `map(int, readline().rstrip())` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tricks you can try to improve upon hdima's answer.

- Put all the code in a function because [Python accesses local variables more efficiently than global variables.](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Local_Variables)
- `for i in xrange(n)` is faster than `while n: n -= 1`, but even better is to avoid the counter variable:
- Use `itertools.islice` to read `n` lines: `for line in islice(stdin, n)`
- `stdout.write('D\n')` is faster than `print 'D'`
- Even faster is to write all once by `stdout.write("".join( <list comprehension> ))` but this makes memory usage dependent on size of input. To avoid that, you could add an outer loop that splits the work in chunks.